# Samba recycle module is not moving deleted files as desired

Tags: linux, debian, network-shares, samba

## Samba recycle module issue

When I delete `<share>/path/to/foo.txt`, the folder `<share>/.recycle/path/to` is created, however, the folder is empty without `foo.txt` present.

### Environment

- Operating system: Debian bullseye (inside a docker container).
- Samba version: 4.13.13-Debian.
- Samba shares mounted as volumes from the host.
- Debian package `samba-vfs-modules` is installed inside the container.

### Samba config

```
[global]

...

#######
# vfs #
#######

vfs objects = crossrename recycle

###################
# vfs crossrename #
###################

crossrename:sizelimit = 5368709120

###############
# vfs recycle #
###############

recycle:keeptree = yes
recycle:versions = yes
recycle:touch = yes
recycle:touch_mtime = no
recycle:minsize = 0
recycle:maxsize = 5368709120
recycle:exclude = *.tmp|*.temp|*.o|*.obj|~$*|*.~??
recycle:repository = .recycle
```

### Question

Why isn't the samba recycle module moving deleted files as desired?

Answer (score 0):

We had excactly the same problems here. It worked out, that it was a permission-issue. It seems that the recycle-module runs with the user-account who actually deleted the file, thus it can be that this process does not have enough rights to create the needed folder-structure ".recycle/..." and/or the moved file at the top folder of the share.

For me the solution was to put the recycle-folders to a dedicated folder outside the shares and give this "base folder" enough permission so that every user account is able to create subfolders and files in there.

TL;DR: The steps I took:

1. Create a dedicated folder for the recycle bins and give it full permissions:

   `mkdir /samba/recycle`

   `chmod 777 /samba/recycle`
2. Change smb.conf to this:

   `[share]`

   `...`

   `recycle:repository = /samba/recycle/%U`

   `recycle:keeptree = yes`

   `recycle:versions = yes`

   `recycle:touch = yes`

Note that I added "%U" to the string. This will add the username to the path, so a file located at `/samba/share/foo/text.txt` would get recycled at `/samba/recycle/<username>/share/foo/text.txt`

HTH